# Loading a library only for the front page

Tags: 8, javascript

I want to load JavaScript only on the home page of my site. I found this preprocess function but I don't know how to customize it for the home page:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/cuddly-slider';
}
```

I was originally including the library I needed in every page of my site, but I only need it on the home page, so I need to figure this out.

Originally I had it in the .info.yml file like so:

```
libraries:
 - 'themename/library'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() == 'view.frontpage.page_1') {
        $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/cuddly-slider';
    }
}
```

Comment: For the front page you could use `if ($variables['is_front'])`. It's already set in theme.inc and it works for other front pages then the frontpage view.

Comment: Note that this only works if you use Drupal's default frontpage view. Better use make-me-alive's solution which always works, also when using a node as frontpage.

Answer (score 8):

The other workaround would be using the method from drupal's path matcher interface which returns true if the current page is the front page.

```
function themename_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

//using the method from the pathmatcherinterface
  if (\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'themename/cuddly-slider';
  }
}
```